# Concurrent programming with fork();, Trouble understanding

Tags: c, concurrency, fork

I am practising concurrent programming, and looking at this piece of code.
I'll have to figure out how many times the program prints Example.
I would assume that it is 10, since main calls try() which forks and then prints two examples.  then it forks again, and returns 4 times. (since there is two fork calls).
In main it then forks again, making the 4 processes to 8. The 8 processes then prints example one time each.
I count that to 10 prints.

Though when I run the code, it prints out 16 "Example".
What am I missing?

```
void try () {
    fork();
    printf("Example\n");
    fork();
    return;

}
int main () {
    try(); fork();
    printf("Example\n");
    exit(0);   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the provided code is exactly what's compiled/running ? Could you precise what headers you're using and if you're linking against standard libc ? Your code, as it is, with the linux kernel fork,  should give 10 examples.

Comment: Try printing the PID along with `Example` so you can see where all the messages are coming from.

Comment: Are you printing to the terminal or redirecting to a file? You'll get different results because of differences in how stdio buffers the output (line-buffered to a terminal, fully-buffered otherwise).

Comment: I guess you're piping the output of your executable. As your main process exit without waiting for its child termination, the output of the child process is duplicated by the pipe process for each of the 4x2 processes born from the `try` second fork as the pipe has no way to know if it is the parent or the child output. Or more probably, there's a race condition on the output. Use `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf` should solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, well good to know that it is supposed to print Example 10 times. fflush(stdout); worked as well. Thanks!